# How to get percentage of certain value in column with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a table:

```
id   value 
a1.  7
a2.  89
a3.  None
a4.  None
```

I want to get percentage of None values in column value. `I don't need percentages of other values in that column, only None values.` How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count_if`:

```sql
WITH dataset(id,value) AS ( VALUES ('a1.','7'), ('a2.','89'), ('a3.','None'), ('a4.','None') )

SELECT count_if(value = 'None') * 1.0/count(*)
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 0.5 |

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(value='None')*100/count(*) from a_table
```

Comment: you can't do sum(value='None') in presto

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when value = 'none' then 1.0 else 0 end) as none_ratio
from t
```